# Is it redundant to use “speech” and “recordings” here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I wrote the following sentence. It is a point listed in my CV to show my work in one project related with my major computer science. I am applying for a graduate university. The missing subject of the sentence is "I". Because the succinct form in CV, all the pointed I listed ingorns the subject. I think the form is very common in CV. You can see the words after "using" as one kind of technology in computer science.

> “Performed speech transcription for course recordings using a recognition framework based on a deep fully convolutional neural network”

I want to express that I converted the course recordings to text. I am not sure whether it is redundant to use “speech” and “recordings” in “performed speech transcription for course recordings” because the two words seem to have the same meaning. If it is redundant, how about using “performed course recordings transcription using a computer technology”? And does “performed course recordings transcription” express the same meaning with my old expressions?

---

Response to the comment

The speech transcription is actually one function of the class assistant app I have developed. So I think maybe I can write

“Implemented a digital speech transcription service to transcribe recordings of courses using a recognition framework based on a deep fully convolutional neural network”.

May I ask that can this new sentence convey my initial meaning clearly?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! You have not given enough information.Who wrote this, Was it you? What kind of job are you applying for? Translator? What does "preformed" mean? Is the speech preformed or is the transcription preformed - or do you mean "performed"? Please give a link to the text if possible.  Please add this information to your question (you can edit the question). Then we will be able to answer. Hope this helps!

Comment: P.S. Please be aware that we are not necessarily specialists in whatever it is that you do. We may not recognise the jargon of your profession. For example, I don't know what a recognition framework is. Also I suspect that you mean "performed" and not "preformed".

Comment: Yes, it should be "performed" not "preformed". I am sorry for my typos.

Comment: You say, *"I performed..."*  I don't think you performed anything.  I think you produced something by using software.  The way your sentence reads at the moment, it seems to say that you used text-to-speech software. However  I think you mean that you used speech-to-text software. I s that correct?

Comment: Yes. Just like Astralbee's guess, I have done some technical work to make it happen, but the computer did the most taxing part.

Comment: You don't implement a service, really. You create a service. **Created a digital speech transcription service for recorded courses using a recognition framework based on a deep, fully convolutional neural network**. [not sure that digital is needed]

Answer (score 1):

> I performed speech transcription for course recordings using a computer technology.

I understand that you are trying to say, in a bullet point, that you have experience using a computer to digitally transcribe some recordings of your course classes into text.

If that is the case then there are a few things you should consider:

- If the computer did the transcription, you didn't really "perform" it. That means *to carry out something through to completion or with great detail*, and although you might have done some technical work to make it happen, the computer did the most taxing part, and I imagine that the purpose of the exercise was to show that the computer technology can reduce the effort of an otherwise manual task.
- "Speech" is not necessarily redundant when speaking about "transcription" - there are other kinds of transcription, for example, *music* transcription. In a speech-transcription environment, it may well be a redundancy, but this is a computer science course and so I think you ought to be specific.
- "Course recordings" may well be understood in context, but would everybody know what that meant? I would recommend you be more specific and say they were recordings of your classes (or whatever they are).
- Finally, "a computer technology" is slightly unusual and perhaps a little vague for university coursework. Most people would use the term "a computer *application*".

Consider this example based on my understanding of what you are trying to say and adapt if necessary:

> Used a digital speech transcription application to transcribe recordings of course lectures/discussions.

Comment: Hi Astralbee. I have already asked the OP to provide the information you are unsure about. Could you wait for the answers - otherwise you are just guessing. Thanks.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica I felt clear enough to make my answer and I'm ready to adjust it when clarification comes in. If the OP's English isn't quite up to explaining then we might need to work with them to get an answer.

Comment: The OP's comment suggests that your guess was correct. I'm just thinking that, as a general rule, it's better to ask than to rush to answer. That's just my opinion though.

Comment: I still think "speech transcription" is ambiguous. In this case it is speech-to-text transcription. The direction is important and on reading quickly the opposite may be inferred.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica The OP is asking if the word "speech" in front of the word "transcription" is a redundancy, which in certain cases it could be, but I've argued that in this case, it isn't. Your suggestion of "...to-text" is certainly redundant. What other kind of transcription from speech is there?

Comment: The OP doesn't use the word "from". The actual quote is *"speech transcription for course recordings"* This suggest to me that text was transcribed into speech that was then used to make course recordings.  In fact the opposite is true. People who read CV's don't tend to pore over a sentence the way we do on SE. They skim for the meaning and ambiguous wording can lead to incorrect conclusions.  P.S. I am aware that "transcribe" implies writing rather than reading but it is often used that way in my experience.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica I have 21 years experience working in IT, one of my many roles is data manager for a digital transcription system, so my "guess" is an educated one.

Comment: If you are on the interview panel then your educated guess will be good.  Not everyone who reads the CV will have your experience.

Comment: Thank you. Actually I want to include the technology, i.e. “using a recognition framework based on a deep fully convolutional neural network” in the point. And can I use "conducted" to replace "performed"? So how about writing “Conducted digital speech transcription to transcribe recordings of courses using a recognition framework based on a deep fully convolutional neural network”?

Comment: "Conducted" has the same issue as "performed" - you didn't actually do the transcription. In the sentence "Conducted digital speech transcription to...." the object of 'conducted' is 'transcription', and you didn't transcribe anything - the computer did it. Perhaps you could give it another object, for example "Conducted digital speech transcription **experiments**", or "**carried out** digitial speech transcription **exercises**"?

Comment: I understand. The speech transcription is actually one function of the class assistant app I have developed. So I think maybe I can use “Realized digital speech transcription function to transcribe recordings of courses using a recognition framework based on a deep fully convolutional neural network”. May I ask that is this sentence accurate and reasonable?

Comment: @Astralbee Hi, I update my sentence in last comment. Now it is "Implemented a digital speech transcription service to transcribe recordings of courses using a recognition framework based on a deep fully convolutional neural network". May I ask that can this new sentence convey my initial meaning clearly? If you can see this comment, please help me by answering this question. Thank you.